# General results about sequences of the form $(1+a_n)^{b_n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I remember reading something about sequences of the form

$$(1+a_n)^{b_n}$$

Where $a_n \to 0$, $b_n \to \infty$, i.e. $1^\infty$ type sequences. It's an $e$-like sequence, but can anything be said? What if $b_n = 1/a_n$? Maybe there are some results with additional assumptions about the sequences?

Comment: What do you mean by $e$-like sequence? $e^\alpha, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ can be an arbitrary positive number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to+\infty$.

- If $a_nb_n\to c$ for some real number $c$, then $(1+a_n)^{b_n}\to\mathrm e^c$.
- If $a_nb_n\to+\infty$, then $(1+a_n)^{b_n}\to+\infty$.
- If $a_nb_n\to-\infty$, then $(1+a_n)^{b_n}\to0$.

Hints:

- For every $a\gt-1$, $(1+a)^{b}=\exp(b\log(1+a))$.
- When $x\to0$, $\log(1+x)\sim x$.